# Required attribute in modal popup on ASP.NET MVC 4 does not work

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

My popup appear and when the TextBox is empty must be appear Required message in my popup but it doesn't appear. and I use DataAnnotaion

this is my view code:

```
@model BLL.Boards
@{

AjaxOptions ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "Board_list",
    LoadingElementId = "loading",
    LoadingElementDuration = 1000,
    OnComplete = "closeDialog('Board')"
};
 }
<fieldset>
<legend>Boards List</legend>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", ajaxOptions))
{
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BoardID)
    <table>
       <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BoardName)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BoardName)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BoardName)</td>

        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.BoardDescription)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BoardDescription)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BoardDescription)</td>
        </tr>


    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" /> 
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel"/>
   }
   </fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you state that these fields should be required? Perhaps an error might appear there

Comment: TextBox in UI I Mean Here EditorFor

Comment: Have you included the jquery validation library?

Comment: On View or Where ..and Give Example